# Extracting data from Oracle Spatial and preserving spatial data

Tags: oracle-spatial

My table currently contains an SDO column that I want to export (along with the rest of the data) but all I have at my disposal is PL SQL Developer.

Is there anything I can do to get at that data and put it into a text or xml format?

I'm not accustomed to working with Oracle Spatial data.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle Spatial has functions in SDO_UTIL-package which you can use to export sdo_geometry as GML, WKT etc. in your select statements.

Answer (score 0):

**DreamCoder** (for Oracle) will export data from Oracle Spatial - using SQL Inserts

> Data Handling:
>    Add, view, edit, search, group, sort and filter data
>   Ability to copy and paste data directly from Excel Ability to delete
>   selected records Able to export data into SQL inserts

http://www.sqldeveloper.net/database-tools/oracle/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

See [SDO-UTIL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-7A79F1C4-FABF-432A-AF94-9E9CB23BBFBA) documentation. Methods such as `SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON` or `SDO_UTIL.TO_JSON_VARCHAR` might fit. For example:

```
SELECT
      B.ID
    , B.GEOM
    , CAST(SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON(B.GEOM) AS VARCHAR2(500)) GEOJSON_TEXT
FROM
    MYTABLE B
```

would return the GeoJSON in a `CLOB` then casted to `VARCHAR2`. The results would look as next:

[image]

There's a specialized forum for Oracle Spatial and Graph here https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/oracle-database-options/spatial which has already a lot of question and answers to basic and complex issues.

> Disclaimer: I work for Oracle Spatial team; however, anything and
>   everything expressed or stated here are my own personal opinions and
>   do not necessarily represent my current and/or former employer’s view.