# Error message when trying to apply SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON operation

Tags: sdo-geometry

I have a shape column of type SDO_GEOMETRY and I was trying to figure out a way to extract the shape data from an Oracle database so I could import it into ArcGIS. I found this post, [Extracting data from Oracle Spatial and preserving spatial data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35650/extracting-data-from-oracle-spatial-and-preserving-spatial-data/339592#339592?newreg=5f5fda6ce8b84311834670c9d51ba044), and tried the code provided with the cast statement but I get these execution errors:

ORA-13199: LRS is not supported
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", Line 7045
ora-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", Line 7066

```
select  t.route_id,
        t.shape,
        cast(sdo_util.to_geojson(t.shape) as varchar2(500)) geojson_text
from SDW_TRANS.MY_TABLE t
```

I am new to working with spatial data inside a database, so I am not sure what this means or what to do about it. I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am using Toad for Oracle.

In case these help:

[image]

Using SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES function:

[image]